# RPN Calculator on iOS - can't figure out why it crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

i'm new in objectiv-c and try to learn it via this lecture-podcast from stanford: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/
very nice thing, but i've got a problem building the rpn-calculator. it crashes when I use popOperand.

here's my model:

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
@end


@implementation CalculatorBrain
@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;

-(NSMutableArray *)operandStack {
    if(_operandStack == nil) {
        _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"zing");

    };
    return _operandStack; 
}




- (void) pushOperand:(double)operand {
     NSLog([[self.operandStack lastObject] stringValue] );
    [self.operandStack addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];
    NSLog(@"----");
     NSLog([[self.operandStack lastObject] stringValue] );

};

-(double) popOperand {
    NSNumber* operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
        if(operandObject) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}






- (double) performOperation:(NSString *)operation{
    double result = 0;
    if([operation isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
        result = [self popOperand] + [self popOperand];
    } else if([operation isEqualToString:@"*"]) {
        result = [self popOperand] * [self popOperand];

    } else if([operation isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
        double subtrahend = [self popOperand];
        result = [self popOperand] - subtrahend; 

    } else if([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
        double divisor = [self popOperand];
        if(divisor) result = [self popOperand] / divisor;
}

    [self pushOperand:result];
    return result;
};



@end
```

really don't know how. the operands are on the stack, but it seems that popOperand can't access?!

Comment: You should post the crash log and the stack trace for getting proper help.

Comment: And can you confirm you are using ARC?

Comment: oh guys, lol. sorry about this, totally my fault: didn't see that I turned Breakpoints on - so it's absolute correct that the app stops. think i need to get some sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh guys, lol. sorry about this, totally my fault: didn't see that I turned Breakpoints on - so it's absolute correct that the app stops. think i need to get some sleep